# How to pass value inside onclick function

Tags: javascript, jsp

My function is

```
var addRiskRule = function(riskKeyValBtn) {

}

onclick="addRiskRule('disabled='disabled');"
```

In my button tag
Is it correct ? getting compilation error
thanks in advance.

Comment: please explain your problem.

Comment: `var addRiskRule = function(riskKeyValBtn) {
  alert(riskKeyValBtn);
}
<button onclick="addRiskRule('disabled=disabled');">Click me!</button>`

Comment: addRiskRule('disabled='disabled') this systex is wrong.

use-->  addRiskRule("disabled='disabled'")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass with `key:value` pair use with object pass to function like this `onclick="addRiskRule({disabled :'disabled'});"`

***suggestion*** => better use Boolean instead of string like `addRiskRule({disabled :true})"`

```js
var addRiskRule = function(riskKeyValBtn) {
button.disabled = riskKeyValBtn.disabled
}

var button = document.getElementById('button')
```

```html
<button onclick="addRiskRule({disabled :true});" id="button" >click</button>
```

***simple method inline function***

```html
<button onclick="this.disabled=true" id="button" >click</button>
```

Comment: if i want to enable this onload and on click i want to disable the option then how can i use this above code???

Comment: @PoojaRS see my updated answer. i was added simple alternate code for disable the button

Answer (score 0):

You can called direct js function in onclick event.

```html
<button onclick="addRiskRule('disabled=disabled');">click</button>

<script>
function addRiskRule(state){
alert(state);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick function have a syntax error. Please try this -

```
onclick="addRiskRule('disabled=\'disabled\'');"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method of using arrow functions and  passing the disabled state directly to `onCLick`

```
onclick={() => (this.setState({disabled : disabled}))) }
```